# Show that divergence is a function of r only

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

In Boas mathematical methods it says that $$\nabla \cdot [ e_{r}F(r)] $$
is a function of only r for any F(r). I've tried to investigate why this is but I can't seem to get it right. When I do 
$$\nabla \cdot [ e_{r}F(r)] = F(r)(\nabla\cdot e_{r}) + e_{r}~\cdot \nabla F(r)$$

$$e_{r}=(cos(\theta)sin(\phi),~sin(\theta)sin(\phi),~0)$$

and

$$\nabla \cdot e_r = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 (cos(\theta)sin(\phi) )\right)= \frac{2cos(\theta)sin(\phi)}{r}$$ $$e_{r}~\cdot \nabla F(r) = (cos(\theta)sin(\phi)\frac{\partial F}{\partial r})$$ and I'm not sure how these combine to make this only a function of r... any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
Define the field ${\bf A} = {\bf e}_r F(r)$, in spherical coordinates

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla\cdot{\bf A} &=& {1 \over r^2}{\partial \left( r^2 A_r \right) \over \partial r}
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta} \left(  \color{blue}{\cancelto{0}{A_\theta}}\sin\theta \right)
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial \color{blue}{\cancelto{0}{A_\varphi}} \over \partial \varphi} \\
&=& \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 F(r))
\end{eqnarray}

which is a function of just $r$

Comment: so A_r doesn't include e_r itself. I guess the notation is just confusing. You take the component of the unit vector e_r which is F(r)

Comment: @DS08 Correct, the radial component of ${\bf A}$ is whatever is accompanying ${\bf e}_r$, in this case $F(r)$